# What are the Benefits and Drawbacks of script embedment

Tags: javascript, html, css

This would be really helpful when making a decision whether to use script embedment or not, so I would like to know some of the factors involved in it

Ps. Simple bullet point answers with an explanation at the end would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "script embedment"? Do you mean putting the script inside the HTML instead of an external file?

Comment: yes, in <script> tags

Comment: The more common term would be *inline*, not "*embedment*", for future reference.